# what's the best way to store username/password for Ant SCP task

Tags: java, maven, ant, scp

I need use a scp task to transfer a whole folder with many sub-folders and files. Currently I use below way:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <configuration>
            <tasks>
            <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/yy" />                     
            <scp file="user:password@host:/home/xx/yy/*" todir="${project.build.directory}/yy" trust="yes"/>
            </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

And it also works if I hard code username and password. But I don't want to make this public in code base. So I make it store in maven-settings.xml like below:

pom.xml

```xml
<scp file="${scpUserName}:${scpUserPassword}@company.net:/home/xx/yy/*" todir="${project.build.directory}/yy" trust="yes"/>
```

settings.xml

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>unix</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>unix</family>
            </os>           
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <scpUserName>xxx</scpUserName>
            <scpUserPassword>xxx</scpUserPassword>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

But I still need make username/password public in Teamcity server so that all agent servers can build whole project successfully. I wonder if there are any better way for this?

Comment: Generate an ssh key and don't store passwords.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks for quick answer. But does that means every building agent server also need install that key before building?

Comment: Installation of ssh key involves placing two files in the `$HOME/.ssh` folder, but yes. Far better than storing passwords (more secure and easier to manage).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  But teamcity agent server is out of our control in our company. Need other way. Thanks. Anyway.

Comment: This transfer is a job for the CI solution and not for Maven. Add a separate step to your build pipeline and let Teamcity solve that...Also use the mechanism of TeamCity to store/handle credentials. This will make your Maven build more clean...

Answer (score 0):

[Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html#How_to_create_a_master_password) explains. First create a master password

```
mvn --encrypt-master-password <password>
```

Enter the result into `settings-security.xml`

```
<settingsSecurity>
  <master>the result here</master>
</settingsSecurity>
```

For the individual passwords, encrypt like this

```
mvn --encrypt-password <password>
```

And you can use it directly in your Maven plugin

```
<properties>
    <scpUserName>xxx<sscpUserName>
    <scpUserPassword>the result here</scpUserPassword>
</properties>
```

When your build server invokes Maven, you will need to supply the master password. You can do so by storing the password using [a password vault](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2017/09/vault/) or something.

Comment: I tried twice. Both failed. one is `<scp file="username:{abN4jRWTfosHwLm9ZlsyGzRVQ8aEFcR/pj6bU3fIvus=}@...` in pom.xml directly . The second time is set {xxx} in settings.xml and inject back to pom.xml .  After reading the documentation again. I believe this only works for `Maven 2.1.0+ now supports **server password encryption**` ,not for properties.

Comment: @QingfeiYuan were you able to find a solution for this? settings-security.xml ends up printing the encrypted password in my teamcity job as well.